# How to show $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I need to show that there is a unique set of real numbers. I found here [https://math.ucr.edu/~res/math205A/uniqreals.pdf](https://math.ucr.edu/%7Eres/math205A/uniqreals.pdf) a way to do it. I didn't go much deep into it because I had problems with the assumption of the existence of the embeddings $e_x$ and $e_y$.

I don't know how to create a set that satisfies Peano axioms if I am given $\mathbb{R}$. I already did the opposite, creating $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{N}$. I first had $\mathbb{N}$ with Peano axioms, then I got $\mathbb{Z}$ with equivalence classes, then I got $\mathbb{Q}$ with equivalence classes again, then I got the reals with Dedekind cuts.

The thing is that I don't know how to reverse it, in the sense that if I am given an arbitrary set of real numbers, how I can get "their" natural numbers (in particular a set that I can do induction).

I'm assuming that any set of real numbers has a $0$ element and an $1$ element, with $0 \neq 1$. A dedekind cut is set $\alpha$ of rational numbers that i) is a proper subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, ii) if $s < r$ and $r \in \alpha$ then $s \in \alpha$, iii) $\alpha$ has no maximal element.

For $\mathbb{R}$ we can assume that we have two operations '$+$' and '$\cdot$'. The addition operation $+$ is commutative, associative, there is a neutral element '$0$', there is a symmetric element (for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is $-x$ such that $x + (-x) = 0$. For the product ·, we can assume that it is commutative, associative, has a neutral element '1' (with $1 \neq 0$), every element that is not zero ($0$) has a inverse (for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x \neq 0$ there is a $x^{-1}$ such that $x \cdot x^{-1} = 1$. Subtraction and division are allowed too.

And $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete ordered field.

I can construct the set $\{\,1,1+1,1+1+\ldots \,\}$.

How can I get a natural number set if I am given $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Which properties of $\Bbb R$ are you allowed to use, and which operations are you allowed to use to construct the desired subset? If you have $1$ and $+$, can you construct the set $\{1,1+1,1+1+1,\dots\}$?

Comment: How about: take the intersection of all subsets $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 \in S$ and whenever $x \in S$ then $x+1 \in S$?  Would that be an admissible construction given any restrictions you're working under?

Comment: Just use induction. You can define $f(0)$ as the additive identity, $f(1)$ as the multiplicative identity, and then inductively define $f(n+1)=f(n)+f(1)$. You can prove that $f(1)>f(0)$ so $f(n+1)>f(n)$, so this is an injection. Induction can also show it preserves multiplication and addition.

Comment: I've edited the question @Karl, thanks.

Comment: hit: the set of the real numbers is the set of rational and irrational numbers. the rational numbers are the set of all possible ratios of two integers. take any natural number and divide by one.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you @DanielSchepler.
And yes, it is admissible construction.

Comment: Thank you @Eric, I think it will solve the problem.

Comment: Remotely related: In the **first-order** theory of the reals, we cannot construct the set of naturals.  (All constructible sets are semi-algebraic: Tarski, I think) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method suggested by @DanielSchepler is used in at least one textbook I know, Fitzpatrick's "Advanced Calculus". One defines a subset $S \subset \mathbb R$ to be *inductive* if it has two properties:

1. $0 \in S$;
2. For all $x \in \mathbb R$, if $x \in S$ then $x+1 \in S$.

$\mathbb N$ is defined to be the intersection of all inductive subsets of $\mathbb R$. To put it another way (thanks @GEdgar), a real number $x$ is in the set $\mathbb N$ if and only if $x$ is an element of every inductive subset of $\mathbb R$.

Lots of properties of $\mathbb N$ are easy to establish on this basis. For example $0$ is the smallest element of $\mathbb N$, because $0 \in \mathbb N$ and $[0,\infty)$ is inductive. And $1$ is the next smallest element, because $1=0+1 \in \mathbb N$ and $\{0\} \cup [1,\infty)$ is inductive.

And of course the key thing to prove is that $\mathbb N$ satisfies Peano's Axioms, using as the successor function $n \mapsto n+1$.

Comment: Instead of using a gigantic intersection of sets, you may re-phrase... a real number $n$ is a natural number iff $n \n S$ for all inductive sets $S$.  It is the same thing, but parhaps students will find it more easily understood.  Another reference for this definition is Spivak's *Calculus*.

Comment: Great, I added that to the answer.